# How could we describe the motion of a ring in a parabolic surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

When you roll a ring on a parabolic surface interesting motion patterns arise(Like in the link shown below). How can we explain these patterns qualitatively and quantitatively?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktDf2xZ1cQ8

Comment: apart from the Euler-disk like motion at the end, I don't think there is any "pattern" arising here given the initial states. The ring acquires energy due to lowering of gravitational potential when it reaches the bottom most point on the surface, which helps it precess till it loses contact with the surface. the nature of the surface may give some different patterns though.

Comment: Questions generally should be self-contained without need to open external links.

Comment: Finding the general equations of motion of the ring is a non-trivial task. In addition, the motion seems to be chaotic.

Comment: What have you tried?